# How can I restrict a string attribute in a RCP extension point?

Tags: xml, eclipse-rcp, restriction

I am defining an extension point for my Eclipse RCP application with some attributes.
One of these attributes is a **string**, which should have **max 3 alphabetical-characters**.

At the moment I have the following definition:

```
<element name="type">
  <complexType>
     <attribute name="type_identifier" type="string" use="required">
        <annotation>
           <documentation>
              Dieser String sollte noch auf maximal 3 Zeichn begrenzt werden
           </documentation>
        </annotation>
     </attribute>
  </complexType> 
</element>
```

Via the editor I can only add enum-restrictions, that show up in the xml-source as:

```
<restriction base="string">
  <enumeration value="blubb">
  </enumeration>
</restriction>
```

But what I want is something like:

```
<restriction base="string">
  <pattern value="[A-Z]{3}">
  </pattern>
</restriction>
```

**Can I use this pattern notification for my extension point?** I can't test the setting at the moment, so a simply "just try and see" isn't possible for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to do that now. You can do that (by adding tooling support) if this feature ever makes into Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=227055

Comment: Not an answer I like, but if no one opposes to that, I'm afraid it's my answer. **Anyone opposing? Plese do!** ;-)

Comment: Okay, so no opposition. Thanks Prakash.